# How to fill CKeditor textarea with content using codeception

Tags: selenium, ckeditor, codeception, rich-text-editor, acceptance-testing

This is a follow up question to this one -- [How to fill a rich text editor field for a Codeception Acceptance test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29168107/7032534)

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33480861/7032534) given on this post, works perfectly on CKeditor version 4.3.2 Standard as seen on this [site](http://yizeng.me/2014/01/31/test-wysiwyg-editors-using-selenium-webdriver/) CKeditor instance but unfortunately does not work on my site's own CKeditor which is version 4.5.10.

Issue with my site's CKeditor - Webdriver throws an error that the name attribute of the `textarea` is not found. On the example, working CKeitor this is not an issue, I am able to gain focus and add custom content to the textarea.

Question - is there a big difference between CKeditor 4.3.2 (working) and version 4.5.10 (not working), that would cause this solution not to function?

Textarea on the working site

`<textarea id="ckeditor" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></textarea>`

Using `id="ckeditor"` works as expected.

Textarea on my site

```
<textarea class="js-text-full text-full form-textarea resize-vertical" data-drupal-selector="edit-field-pck-headline-0-value" aria-describedby="edit-field-pck-headline-0--54Lxz-5-U5g--description" id="edit-field-pck-headline-0-value--im63vH7ew8s" name="field_pck_headline[0][value]" rows="5" cols="60" placeholder="" data-editor-active-text-format="full_html" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></textarea>
```

I am using the `name="field_pck_headline[0][value]"` but webdriver cant locate this

Thanks for any help in getting focus to the CKeditor textarea on my version (4.5.10). I am glad to provide more details, let me know.

Here is a screen grab of my local CKEditor textarea that I am attempting to gain focus to [My local CKEditor textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKXKH.png)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be related to the CKEditor since Selenium can't find the text area. So it's either a timing issue or your editor is in a frame and you need to switch to it.

Comment: CKEditor 8 doesn't exits. That would be the version of some wrapper or anything else, but not CKEditor itself.

Comment: I dig some digging and found that 8.1.8 is referring to my Drupal version.
I am using Drupal Core's version of CKEditor (4.5.10)
I have attached a screen grab of the CKEditor I am attempting to gain focus to. I do not see an extra iFrame (in comparison to the example that is working). So not sure what is preventing textarea focus. Thank you much!

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me (testing a Drupal 7 site):

```
$I->executeJS("CKEDITOR.instances['edit-body-und-0-value'].setData('Text entered via Selenium.');");
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm using CKeditor 4.4, selenium webdriver in acceptance test.

this works for me. following this

[How to fill a rich text editor field for a Codeception Acceptance test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168107/how-to-fill-a-rich-text-editor-field-for-a-codeception-acceptance-test/33480861#33480861)

html of page:

```
<div id="cke_1_contents" class="cke_contents cke_reset">

    <iframe class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" frameborder="0" src="">
```

in my test:

```
$I->fillCkEditorById('1_contents', 'your added content');
```

USE 1_contents AS A PARAM